# Sharepoint Embed Webpart Cannot find file

Tags: iframe, sharepoint-online

I'm using the Embed webpart in Sharepoint Online on the communication site and have problems with using the right url or storing the data on the right place. I use the next iframe:

`<iframe src="https://******.sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/Webmap/index.aspx#11/52.1/5.62" width="100%" height="470"></iframe>`

I have uploaded the map Webmap with its content on SiteAssets. Webmap consists, besides index.aspx, of the following subdirectories: css, data, images, js, legend, markers, webfonts. 
The error message is "File not found"

(The message is translated by me in English so maybe it is slightly different ie Cannot find file) 
Where should I put the Webmap map so I can use a working URL in the Webpart or what else could be wrong? Please help.